# Is there a way to find maximum bottleneck path in a DAG in O(|E|) time?

Tags: directed-acyclic-graphs, bottleneck

I am working on a project and have a problem relating to finding a maximum bottleneck path from *s* to *t* in a directed acyclic graph. The problem is as follows:

Define the bottleneck of a path from *s* to *t* in a graph to be the smallest capacity out of the capacities of the edges in the path. Is it possible to find a path from *s* to *t* with the maximum bottleneck capacity in *O(|E|)* time, where *|E|* is the number of edges in the graph? How would I make such an algorithm?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273) (don't just change your question to "How").
Please see: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a breadth-first search for `t` starting at node `s`. As your graph is acyclic, this search is guaranteed to end, either returning all paths from `s` to `t` or no paths, if there is none such path.

- While searching keep track of all paths and their bottlenecks.
- When you reach an intermediate node `x` which was already visited via some other path, check, which of the known paths from `s -> x` has the highest bottleneck and keep only that one.
- The same also applies for `t`, ie if you reach `t`, check if you already have found any other path to `t` and keep only the path with the maximum bottleneck.
- Once the search has ended, only the path with the maximum bottleneck will remain (if there is any)

As this approach visits each edge at most once, it's in *O(|E|)*